# map-creation synonym of cartography

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [map-creation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-creation) be a synonym of [cartography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography)? There are three questions tagged [cartography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography) and two tagged [map-creation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-creation). They mean the same thing, one is just a specialized term and the other is laymen's speech. So I think they should be synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

I think there are differences but not enough to make much difference without causing a lot of confusion.

**longer**

I think there are some subtle differences, I think map creation is about drawing maps from a designed world. Whereas cartography is about the design of how the maps and coordinate systems work.

For example if I was to ask about implementing a coordinate system based on bearing and distance to a particular point that's cartography. If I wanted to know how to represent a church on my map that's map building.

I've actually changed my mind since beginning this post. While I think there is a a difference I think these distinctions are probably too subtle and would simply cause confusion.

I would merge them because although there are minor differences I think it would be more valuable to have all the map type questions together.

Comment: meant want to add a line in the middle (using markdown like this `-------`, to show the new post from the  old. Or just completely change the feel of the whole post as no one has voted on it. (BTW, I'm up voting the second portion.

Comment: Coordinate systems are a general aspect of geography (or more broadly "planetography") and touch on just about everything.  The main input into them is probably Geodesy (the measurement of the shape of the Earth).  Cartography is the art of presenting geographic information and very much includes the selection of symbols for representing features.