# Cartography synonym of map-making

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have just proposed [cartography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography) as a synonym of [map-making](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-making), can the community look at this and see what they think?

I think [cartography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography) and [map-making](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-making) should be made synonyms because they are essentially the same thing. They have subtle differences, but not enough to be worth having seperate tags. For a full discussion on this, see [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/map-creation-synonym-of-cartography). For further argument, map making is redirected to cartography on wikipedia.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/map-making/synonyms

Comment: possible duplicate of [map-creation synonym of cartography](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/130/map-creation-synonym-of-cartography)

Comment: Technically it's not a dupe, it's map-creation and map-making both synonyms of cartography

Comment: I agree with DonyorM, when you look at the actual question from both tags, you can't really separate them.

Comment: I think cartography should be the main tag, and map-making the synonym, not the other way round.